# I get this output trying to install MySQL Workbench on Debian Linux what should i do?

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mysql-workbench

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.1.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.1.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:49 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/Descargas/programas/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-src/wb-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I get this output error after typing `cmake [-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr] ..`

Comment: apt-get install pkg-config maybe and try again?

Comment: yes a couple days ago but now i get this wrong output and i dont know what to do.  CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindGTK2.cmake:647 (message):
  Could not find GTK2 include directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:41 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/Descargas/programas/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-src/wb-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: You need to install all the required compiling tools